# Mapping UniProt id to Entrez id

Tags: r, identifiers

How can we get mapping from UniProt id to Entrez ID? I have UniProt id, but want to convert those ids to Entrez or Ensembl id.

Comment: The FTP sites of UniProt and Ensembl have mapping tables.

Comment: If you use R and you have a model organism, there are bioconductor packages like org.Hs.eg.db that allow you to map

Comment: If you can reformulate the question @user224050 to include why this is relevant to you and your investigation. There are perfectly good answers here, but right now the question is likely to 'bomb out', most likely get closed because anyone who has not encounteed the problem would not understand the question and it must be understandable to a broad audience.

Comment: I think this is exactly the type of question we need - concise and googleable. I just took the liberty of making the title more informative (hope OP won't mind).

Comment: Baring the response being "accepted" for the answer below, I agree the question worked veery well in this instance. What we don't want is... thoughtful answer ... OP oh that wasn't the question in my mind. In this case that didn't happen

Answer (score 2):

The Retrieve/ID mapping tool from Uniprot allows you to convert from Uniprot to entrez ID and vice-versa. It is available [here](https://www.uniprot.org/uploadlists/). Just select the appropriate values in the `2.Selection options` panel.

Comment: With thanks from me as well.

Comment: Thank you very much!